# Photocell resistor and thermistor

Tags: circuit-design

Details:

I am trying to build a circuit using a photocell resistor, a thermistor resistor, an LM324 op-amp, and of course regular resistors and wires. I am also using Analog Discovery 2 to provide power for my circuit.

Goals:

My goal is to build a circuit (using the above compenents) where one LED lights when the shadow passes the photocell and turns off when some heat is introduced in the thermistor.

Attempt:

I have tried many designs and nothing works. I tried putting the sensors in parallel and series with the LED. This didn't work. I tried using two op-amps, but I was unsuccessful again. I am new to electric engineering so maybe this is why I am struggling so much.

Any advice/suggestions with circuit design or even a systematic diagram would be really helpful. If you know of any similar project like this on the internet that I could study and learn from, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? Please show us what you've been able to do so far.

Comment: Could you give us a schematic or some sort of diagram? I may be wrong, but couldn't you use zener diodes, hook the thermistor and photocell up with voltage dividers, measure what voltage they reach at the needed temp/ brightness level and use the the zener diodes for those two specific breakdown voltages to trigger the LED?

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions. Show us the schematics for the circuits you built and explain what they actually did and what you wanted them to do.